# Options when compiling R code

Tags: r, compilation, compiler-optimization, jit

I usually just copy-paste (or `source(..)`) my R code on a console, so that compilation in R is very obscure to me.

When compiling C++ code, one can give indication to the compiler (such as `#define` or `#pragma` for example) or specific flag to indicate level of optimization (such as `-o2` for example).

Is there an equivalent of `#InfoForCompiler` or `-o2` in R? Is it possible to make specific choices about how and when (when defining the function or when calling the function for the first time) an R code is compiled?

Comment: R is interpreted, not compiled, and it does not use a preprocessor, so there is really no equivalent to either of those things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whichever way you choose to compile, from `R CMD COMPILE` to `R CMD INSTALL` for a package, or via something like `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`, it will *always* be invoked by R itself and

- R respect environment variables like `CXXFLAGS`
- R looks up its values in `$RHOME/etc/Makeconf` (on Debian systems also in `/etc/R/Makeconf`
- These can be overriden via `~/.R/Makeconf` on a per-user basis.

But as @nrussell commented this will *not* affect your already-compiled R interpreter, only incremental new compilations -- for example package installations.

To change this for R itself, you have to essentially rebuild R from source.